# Cursor sliding towards botton right corner on every mouse input

Tags: wine, mouse, fullscreen

When using Wine to run Worms 4 mayhem, all mouse input events (mouse movement, button pressing and even scrolling) move cursor towards bottom-right corner a little. I had tried various configurations including virtual desktop, disabling mouse acceleration and disabling touchpad. I had no chance to try other fullscreen apps yet.
 Did someone encountered same or similar problem and posses knowledge how to fix it ?

Edit :
I tried my favorite Brutal Doom Black Edition using linux version of GZDoom and cursor have some offset from real positin. Can it be caused by XFce ?

Edit2 :
Just I tried AgeOfEmires 2 and cursor is fine... Strange.

Comment: it seems worms 4 mayhem has had mouse issues before
https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=6971

Comment: @MichaelWarner Man, that was fixed 2011-05-27. There is no word about Worms 4 Mayhem and bug is called "Mouse "escapes" window or is confined to an area in the full screen program" what is not my problem, my problem is about wrong reading of mouse input moving cursor towards right-botton corner on every input. But is is not only in Wine, linux version of GZDoom have problem with cursor offset and it natively runs on linux.

Comment: All I'm pointing out is it has a history of mouse problems.

Comment: @MichaelWarner Every program has long history of problems. But is is not only about Wine, programs that runs on Ubuntu natively have fullscreen problems too.

Comment: Please, try latest wine version *(`3.14` ATM)*, and if it still doesn't work, [report a bug to wine](https://bugs.winehq.org/).

Comment: @Hi-Angel I started using crossover but problem presist. Should I report it to wine or to crossover ?

Comment: Hmm. It's a good question, I didn't use CrossOver. Okay, in this case I think it's better to [report the bug to crossover](https://www.codeweavers.com/support/bugs), since you should have a paid support for it, which means it's more likely to get fixed soon.

Comment: Yeah, FTR, CrossOver are using a patched Wine; but it's not like they're not contributing some of patches back — in fact, CodeWeavers are the biggest contributors to Wine project.

Comment: @Hi-Angel I tried but CrossOver not accepting new bugs

Comment: This is weird. Okay, then report the bug to wine, but before, make sure you've tested latest wine version.